# Multiple Redis servers on single Google cloud machine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, redis, google-cloud-functions

I am running a Redis server on a g1-small machine on Google cloud. I want to rate limit my Google cloud functions with this Redis server. However, when I have two or more functions, the same Redis database is used. Thus the limit on the functions is not separated. Is it possible to run two different Redis servers on the same machine? Or do you have other options to rate limit my Google cloud functions.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to use a heavy-wight service (Compute Engine plus Redis) to manage a light-weight service? In addition, you converting an autoscaling, highly available service and making it dependent on a single low availability service. To answer your question depends on information not in your question such as what does the service do, what types of clients/services does it support, can you use authorization, etc.

Comment: @JohnHanley I want to create an API with google cloud functions and limit access for the user to it. I'll create a separate function for each user and authorise it with CORS. Then I want to set a limit on the calls per month.

Answer (score 0):

To apply a rate-limit is from the Cloud Function, If you are using Node.js there is a rate-limiting library in a Cloud Function to limit function invocations. Here I leave you the link to a document where you can see how to use these techniques to limit function invocations by the IP address of the caller.
https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cloud-functions-rate-limiting